# Cypress - how to properly detect for JS errors in a page

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress, sinon, sinon-chai

I am in the process of writing a spec file with N it(s), where each it will visit a specific page of the application and will return the number of errors/warning in the applications.

I've posted also here: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4808

The solution offered does not seem to work:

```
it('should spy window.error', () => {
  cy.visit('https://www.spiegel.de/', {
    onBeforeLoad(win) {
      cy.spy(win.console, 'error').as('spyWinConsoleError');
      cy.spy(win.console, 'warn').as('spyWinConsoleWarn');
    },
  })
  console.error('questo e errore')
  cy.get('@spyWinConsoleError').should('be.calledOnce');
});
```

Any idea?

Comment: That seems like a better case for a unit test. Why do you need to test it on the browser? Can you post the error?

Comment: The error is showed to the github issues page I shared. 
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4808#issuecomment-776246285

we want to test this on a real browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things to note,

- there are two window objects in a Cypress test, the one the test runs in and the one the app runs in. Your call to `console.error('questo e errore')` is to the first, but your spy is on the second.
- test code runs faster than Cypress commands, so `console.error('questo e errore')` is running before `cy.visit()` gets done.

These example all work,

**Spying on runner window console**

```js
it('should spy on RUNNER window.error', () => {
  cy.spy(window.console, 'error').as('spyWinConsoleError');
  console.error('questo e errore')
  cy.get('@spyWinConsoleError').should('be.calledOnce');
});
```

**Spying on app window console**

```js
it('should spy on APP window.error', () => {
  const win = cy.state('window')
  cy.spy(win.console, 'error').as('spyWinConsoleError');
  
  win.console.error('questo e errore')
  cy.get('@spyWinConsoleError').should('be.calledOnce');
});
```

**Catching an actual app error**

```js
it('should spy window.error', () => {
  cy.visit('../app/spy-on-win-error.html', {
    onBeforeLoad(win) {
      cy.spy(win.console, 'error').as('spyWinConsoleError');
    },
  })
  cy.get('@spyWinConsoleError').should('be.calledWith', 'from app');
});
```

```
<body>
  <script>
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.error('from app')
    }, 1000)
  </script>
</body>
```

**Waiting for spiegel.de to load**

```js
it('should spy window.error', () => {

  cy.visit('https://www.spiegel.de/', {
    onBeforeLoad(win) {
      cy.spy(win.console, 'error').as('spyWinConsoleError');
      win.console.error("questo è l'errore due");      // call here after spy is set
    },
  })

  cy.get('@spyWinConsoleError')
    .should('be.calledOnce');
});
```