# Test the new Error() message with Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I went over the documentation of cypress and i did not find any details about how to test if a error was thrown in javascript like:
 `throw new Error('my error');`
 Question:
Is there a solution to test if a error wast thrown like i showed above, or to test the message?

Comment: Could this answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66154889/cypress-how-to-properly-detect-for-js-errors-in-a-page

Comment: @Skip, no, i want maybe to find a solution to mock the `throw new Error` using Cypress. Could you help? Because when i run tests they failed because of the error.

Answer (score 3):

Such an error is an [Uncaught exception from your application](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/error-messages#Uncaught-exceptions-from-your-application)

> When Cypress detects an uncaught exception in your application, it will fail the currently running test.
>
> You can turn off this behavior globally or conditionally with the uncaught:exception event. Please see the Catalog of Events for examples.

```js
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  expect(err.message).to.eq('my error')
  return false
})
```

Comment: if i do this anyway i get that issue, like i ca not catch that error. Do you know where could be the issue?

Comment: i solved using `done`. But is unclear why done helped. Could you help?